# Add a br tag in between of the text (ellipsis in second line)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my project, I am trying to add a `<br>` element inside a element `div`. So, that I can show ellipsis on second line.

Here is the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/aCnS5/) in which I *hardcoded* the `br` tag.

```
<div>hellohel<br>lohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohello</div>
```

I am trying to add the `br` tag at **very end of the first line** (*renderred by the browser*) in the `div` element.

I don't want to hardcode the `br` tag as the page needs to be responsive. and also later I am trying to remove the `br` tag when the page is resized (So, that I can add it again in new position).

If I can achieve the above solution my problem will be solved. If there are any other alternative solutions then please share.

PS: I am not looking for any plugins to include.

**Answer**(*updated*): [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/zmJVv/3/)

*modified one for bigger projects:* [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zmJVv/5/)

Comment: I'm not sure of how to write this, but can't you add in a span class here and do a add.class remove.class scenario where if(the page gets resized) .then (this will happen)?

Comment: I know you said no plugins, but this might help? http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/

Comment: how about using innerHTML for this?

Comment: does the first line have a . ending it ?

Comment: What is **"first line"** that you're referring to? Is it your first line or is it first line as it's rendered by the browser?

Comment: @PatsyIssa I can't differentiate on it

Comment: @RobertKoritnik first line renderred by the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should check out [Rob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17882583/1348195). JS is a really extreme mean to solve these sort of issues.

---

I wrote a short utility function for you that does what you want, it will look cut the first line of al emenet an add a `<br>` after it. This will let you keep `ellipsis` on the second line.

Here is generally how it works:

- Create a mock element
- Start writing to it one letter at a time
- Stop right before its width is bigger than your element
- Set the HTML of the element to the text you matched + `<br />` + the rest of the text

Here is the code:

```
function appendBR(element){
    var text = element.textContent.split("");
    var width = element.offsetWidth;
    var el = document.createElement("el");
    document.body.appendChild(el);
    while(text.length > 0){
        el.textContent+=text.shift();
        if(el.offsetWidth > width-20){
            element.innerHTML = el.textContent+"<br />"+text.join("");
            document.body.removeChild(el);
            return;
        }
    }    
    document.body.removeChild(el);
}

var container = document.getElementById("first");
appendBR(container);
```

#### [Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BdUZD/)

Note, if you want it to be resistant to changing the size of the window, you can add a listener (using addEventListener and shimming with attachEvent) to scroll. Here is [a working fiddle for that](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/zmJVv/1/).

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you're trying to use the wrong tool for the given task. To automatically wrap long lines, use the [`word-break: break-all;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break) CSS property. It's supported by all major browsers (Opera 12 doesn't support it, but Chromium-based Opera 15 does).

The advantage of this method over any JavaScript method is that it properly deals with unicode characters (otherwise you would have to manually calculate the width of each word, render the result, validate the width and try again - which is as expensive as it sounds).

To get your demo to work, remove `overflow:hidden` and change `white-space:pre;` to `white-space:pre-wrap`.

Comment: I was also suspecting he's looking for this... Which is even better as browser would handle all of this with proper CSS.

Comment: I want to show ellipsis on second line. I tried your explanation which is showing something like this http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/aCnS5/2/

Comment: The combination of `break-all` and `text-overflow` doesn't seem to work... Ellipsis doesn't get displayed... and @Mr_Green: would you like ellipsis to **allways** display or just when there's more text after the second line?

Comment: when there's more text after the second line.. I did coded myself but it is not effective http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/txcWN/7/. messing up on shrink.

Comment: @Mr_Green That's a though one. `white-space:pre-wrap` and `word-break:break-all` instructs the browser to wrap as much as possible. The consequence is that text never overflows, so `text-overflow` never gets a chance to kick in. What's the problem you're trying to solve? "Fit as much as possible in a box, and show ellipses at the bottom if it doesn't fit"?

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use this for ellipsis if you can:

```
width:80px;
overflow:hidden; 
text-overflow:ellipsis;
white-space:nowrap;
```

This will automatically add `...` to the end of string if there's not enough space.

Comment: This will give ellipsis on first line. which I know. I am trying to get ellipsis on second line. I am looking for a solution which is responsive because the width will be in percentage.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is how u want it..

I have updated the fiddle:

**[Check the Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aCnS5/1/)**

```
div {
    min-width: 45px;
    width:40%;
    max-height:40px;
    white-space: pre-wrap; /* css-3 */    
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
    white-space: -pre-wrap; /* Opera 4-6 */    
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap; /* Opera 7 */    
    word-wrap: break-word; /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */;
    overflow:auto;

    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    border: 1px solid green;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```